# Converting fractions into integers and dividing them in an if statement only returning zero

Tags: vb.net

Purpose: Take two fractions inputted on another platform and by user and evaluate them with `IsNothing`. If they aren't integers or strings that can be converted, run through `Frac2Num` (attached, I know this works, not the focus. Code created by Jeff Arms of Arecon Data).

It then checks to see if value A2 is greater than one. If so, then performs the math function (A2/2) - (A1/2) and then returns that value. Else, it returns 0.

So far I have only been able to return 0, so something with how it is reading the values or how its returning the value after the equation is messing it up, I think.

Main function:

```
Public Function MyFunction(ByVal A1 As String, ByVal A2 As String) As Integer
MyFunction= 0
Try
    Dim B1 As Double
    Dim B2 As Double


    If IsNothing(A1) Then Return 0 'If the user provides no values, return 0.
    If IsNothing(A2) Then Return 0 'If the user provides no values, return 0.

    If IsNumeric(A1) = True Then
        B1 = CDbl(A1)
    Else
        B1 = Frac2Num(A1)
    End If  'If the value is an integer or convertible string, convert value to double.  If not, run through Frac2Num function.

    If IsNumeric(A2) = True Then
        B2 = CDbl(A2)
    Else
        B2 = Frac2Num(A2)
    End If

    If A2 > 1 Then
        MyFunction= (A2 / 2) - (A1 / 2)
        Return MyFunction
    Else MyFunction= 0
    End If 'If A2 is greater than one, then MyFunction = value created by equation.

Catch ex As Exception

End Try
```

Frac2Num function:

```
Function Frac2Num(ByVal X As String) As Double
    Dim P As Integer, N As Double, Num As Double, Den As Double
    X = Trim$(X)
    P = InStr(X, "/")
    If P = 0 Then
        N = Val(X)
    Else
        Den = Val(Mid$(X, P + 1))
        If Den = 0 Then Error 11    ' Divide by zero
        X = Trim$(Left$(X, P - 1))
        P = InStr(X, " ")
        If P = 0 Then
            Num = Val(X)
        Else
            Num = Val(Mid$(X, P + 1))
            N = Val(Left$(X, P - 1))
        End If
    End If
    If Den <> 0 Then
        N = N + Num / Den
    End If
    Frac2Num = N
End Function
```

Returning:

```
Sub Main()
    Dim result As Integer

    result = MyFunction("8 1/2", "8 5/8") 'Function called with example values.
    Console.WriteLine(result)
    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub
```

Comment: have you tried stepping through to see where the logic takes you? First questions that pop into mind are: does IsNumeric return true for compound (complex) fractions? Does CDBL work on those same values? Also, this code looks more VBA-ish than .NET.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, in the end of your code you are trying to convert a fraction string directly to a number, witch is causing your code to generate an exception and go to the `Catch` block

change it to

```
'You are using A1 and A2, change it to B1 and B@
If B2 > 1 Then
    MyFunction = (B2 * 1.0 / 2) - (B1 * 1.0 / 2)
    Return MyFunction
Else : MyFunction = 0
End If
```

also, you are returning an integer and assigning the result to an integer. Even if the result was computed properly in your example case it will not be evaluated correctly. Changing it to Double should solve it.

```
Public Function MyFunction(ByVal A1 As String, ByVal A2 As String) As Double
```

and

```
Dim result As Double
result = MyFunction("8 1/2", "8 5/8")
```

Comment: That did it!  Thank you very much!

Comment: You are welcome! Please, if it is the correct answer for your question mark it as answer properly. If you have any other question we will be happy to help you finding the solution.